# Asp.net Static Variable Life time Across Refresh and PostBack

Tags: asp.net, static

WorkAround:

I have declared a class level Public static variable and initialized with a value 0 in the environment of ASP.NET 3.5
In load event I  Incremented by 1 of that variable

Problem:

1. After getting page refresh and even `Postback`, I am getting latest values of that  variable.
   A variable declared as `STATIC` , not getting reset by Page refresh and `Postback`?
2. I just close the browser and close the VS 2008 IDE - even though while i am reopen, rerun the same web application, I am getting last incremented value, Not 0.
   I am wondering how this is possible after i close application.

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static variables are valid for the entire AppDomain. When you close your browser you don't close the application as it continues to execute on the web server. Oh and forgot to mention: try to avoid using static variables in multi-threaded applications without proper locking mechanisms or you may run into race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Static variables keep their values for the duration of the application domain.

It will survive many browser sessions until you restart the web server (IIS) or until it restarts on its own (when it decides it needs to refresh its used resources).

Comment: And sometimes when closing VS2008 the Cassini server will still be active and not unloaded. Boy that makes for some fun global.asax debugging.

Comment: Never happened to me happily.

Answer (score 2):

> Static variables are valid for the
>   entire AppDomain.

Closing VS 2008 IDE and/or stopping debugging is not always enough to get the AppDomain that is hosting your website to such down.  (Even when the website is hosted in the Vs 2008 tests server.

> One easy solution is the "touch" the
>   web.config file.   (E.g. add a space
>   and save it)

That will get the next request processed in a new app-domain.